# Google maps directions destination alias

Tags: google-maps-api-3, driving-directions

I have a page at http://www.no1hastings.check.com.au/directions.html where visitors can get directions from anywhere to a fixed point. The destination that the Google geocoder recognises is a street address (1 Morwong Drive) but I would like it to display the name of the building there (No. 1 in Hastings Street) which Google doesn't recognise.

Is there way to set the street address as the destination but alias it to the building name when the result is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to modify the string in the response before sending it to the DirectionsRenderer:

```
function calcRoute() {
  var request = {
    origin: 'Brisbane QLD Australia Australia',
    //  origin: 'Brisbane Qld, Australia',
    destination: '1 Morwong Drive, Noosa Heads Qld, Australia',
    //  waypoints:[{location: 'Bourke, NSW'}, {location: 'Broken Hill, NSW'}],
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var lastleg = route.legs[route.legs.length-1];
      response.routes[0].legs[route.legs.length-1].end_address = 'No. 1 in Hastings Street';
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else alert("Directions request failed: "+status);
  });
}
```

To handle the case where the directions are changed by the directionsRenderer (i.e. for dragging the origin), you could do something like this (where changeEnd is a global and set to false), note that it will have undesireable results if the user drags the destination (you may want to prevent that: [Google maps api v3 Two markers one fixed one dragged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966766/google-maps-api-v3-two-markers-one-fixed-one-dragged/16972214#16972214)):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
  computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.directions);
   if (!changeEnd) {
     var response = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
     var route = response.routes[0];
     var lastleg = route.legs[route.legs.length-1];
     response.routes[0].legs[route.legs.length-1].end_address = 'No. 1 in Hastings Street';
     changeEnd = true;
     directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
   } else changeEnd = false;
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly if one selects a starting point from the drop down list. If though one drags the A marker to a different point it then shows the street address instead of 'No. 1 in Hastings Street'.

Comment: Did you try adding code to handle that case?  You might be better off turning off draggable directions.

Comment: Or something like [this, which only allows one draggable marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966766/google-maps-api-v3-two-markers-one-fixed-one-dragged/16972214#16972214)